# Multiple Route file in laravel 5/ multiple folder for routes

Tags: php, file, routes, laravel-5

I have Getting stucked with one problem. creating the folder for routes and define the different file for different route.  like i have 3 type of user. admin , user1,user2. i want to create 3 different subfolder for routes. i seacrh google and implement this. but its is not working.
anyone help me.

thanks

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use File;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function($router)
        {
            foreach(File::allFiles(app_path().'/Http/Routes') as $route) {
                require_once $route->getPathname();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "folder"? You want to save routes in separate files/folders? You want separate "folder" in the url?

Answer (score 1):

It may help others:

I have multi tenant application serving 4 subdomains from a single Laravel application. I wanted to keep the routes for each subdomain in the separate file.

Based on the accepted answer, in Laravel 5.4 I modified the `mapWebRoutes()` method in the `RouteServiceProvider.php` as below:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'domain' => 'subdomain1.yoursba.com',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/subdomain1Routes.php');
    });

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'domain' => 'subdomain2.yoursba.com',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/subdomain2Routes.php');
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is late but for others check out this blog post. it may be exactly what you are looking for https://arjunphp.com/multiple-routes-files-laravel-5/